# Swift Dates and Times

Tags: swift, date, time, nstimeinterval

I am trying to work out the number of seconds between two times.

My proposed method is to get the Unix times for ' Date 1' and 'Date 2' then deduct them to get the number of seconds.

The second date will be in the format of a string.

How do I convert a string into a unix time in swift?

Any help Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSDate` and the method: `timeIntervalSinceDate` which returns a `NSTimeInterval` which is a `Double` value in seconds.

`NSDateFormatter` method `dateFromString` will covert a date expressed as a string into an `NSDate`. See: [Date Field SymbolTable.](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for date/time formats.

Try writing the code, add it to the question if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
// Your string date
let str = "2016-10-10 12:01:00"
// Create a new DateFormatter
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
// Set the dateFormat
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
// Create a new date object from your string
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: str)
// get the unix value
let timestamp = date?.timeIntervalSince1970
```